# C++ Math Tokenizer / Parser Error

Tags: c++, math, infinite-loop, tokenize

I am trying to make a basic math tokenizer / parser in C++, which gets the input from the console and then tokenizes it (Eventually going on to parse it). However, when I tried `5 * 5`, I got a bit of a problem:

I would get the desired tokenized value of `53 -1 53` printed to the console, but after, I also got an infinite amount of `-1`s (it kept printing). What is the problem?

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "tokenizer.h"

int main(void){
    std::cout << "Please enter a mathematical expression" << std::endl;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream input(line);
    tokenizer t;
    std::vector<token> tokens(t.getTokens(&input));
}
```

*tokenizer.h*

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "tokens.h"

class tokenizer{
public:
    std::vector<token> getTokens(std::istringstream* input);
};
```

*tokens.h*

```
typedef const signed int token;
enum tokens{
    mul = -1,
    mDiv = -2,
    add = -3,
    sub = -4,
    mPow = -5,
    lparen = -6,
    rparen = -7,
    decpoint = -8
};
```

*tokenizer.cpp*

```
#include "tokenizer.h"
#include <iostream>

token getToken(int tok);

std::vector<token> tokenizer::getTokens(std::istringstream* input){
    std::vector<token> tokens;
    while(input){
        int t = input->get();
        if(!isspace(t)){
            std::cout << getToken(t) << " "; // I added this line to see the values being added
            tokens.push_back(getToken(t));
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}

token getToken(int tok){
    switch((char)tok){
    case '*':
        return tokens::mul;
    case '/':
        return tokens::mDiv;
    case '+':
        return tokens::add;
    case '-':
        return tokens::sub;
    case '^':
        return tokens::mPow;
    case '(':
        return tokens::lparen;
    case ')':
        return tokens::rparen;
    case '.':
        return tokens::decpoint;
    }
    return tok;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what values are going INTO getToken, and if it is getting a -1 in, what it means for input->get() to return -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to `std::istringstream` will evaluate to true even after the whole input was read, so long as it is not null.

Comment: Use while(*input){...}

Comment: pass it in by reference, instead of pointer.  Then your `while(input)` will evaluate if the input is still good.

Answer (score 1):

The loop condition in `tokenizer::getTokens()` will always evaluate to true in your code. You could try changing `while(input)` to `while(input->good())`.